# jmeter response "getting this error 1|#||4|33|pageRedirect||%2fBFLWebPOS%2fSessionExpire, how to solve this issue"

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run the created scripts and getting message in response as following.

```
error 1|#||4|33|pageRedirect||%2fBFLWebPOS%2fSessionExpire
```

what is the significant this in `JMeter`?

Comment: It does mean that the Cookies are expired use the latest. Try by adding `HTTP Cookie Manager` to the script and execute. If not working, then you need to correlate the session related information,

Comment: can you share some parts of your script?

Comment: HTTP Cookie Manager I have added at thread group and issue resolved till 3 sampler, now getting this "1|#||4|13393|updatePanel|UpdatePanel1| .....some response" and next all samplers getting 70|error|500|The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.|..

Comment: man lonut - can you please share email id I will share the scripts?

Comment: Did this issue get resolved?